# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects - Android 4.1 and Retrolambda

Tags: java, android, lambda, retrolambda

I am experiencing a crash that I am not 100% sure what is going on. My suspicions are that it has to do with what retrolambda is doing under the hood to achieve the use of lambdas pre-Java 8. I am receiving the following crash:

```
04-21 13:50:32.609 1199-1199/com.ariets.af.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.Objects
at com.abercrombie.android.sdk.AFSDK.initialize(AFSDK.java:154)
at com.ariets.af.data.sdk.SDKClient.observeSdkInitialize(SDKClient.java:474)
at com.ariets.af.ui.splash.AfSplashScreenPresenterImpl.setupAfSdk(AfSplashScreenPresenterImpl.java:69)
at com.ariets.af.ui.splash.AFSplashScreenActivity.onCreate(AFSplashScreenActivity.java:84)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)                              
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am *not* using `java.util.Objects` directly (doing a search for that in my code, in fact, does not bring up any results). The following is an exerpt of what my code looks like:

```
findRegion().flatMap(afRegion -> setupSharedVariables(afRegion))
    .flatMap(afRegion -> fetchContent(afRegion)) // THIS IS WHERE THE CRASH OCCURS
    .flatMap(sessionHandler::initializeSession)
    .doOnNext(complete -> {
      isStarted = true;
      logTime("startUp successfully completed", start);
    });
```

Some background on the setup of the application:

- We're using retrolambda to support using lambdas on previous versions of Java.
- Our minSdkVersion is 16.
- A couple of gradle plugins we're using (in case any of these will provide some info as to what's going on):

  - [Retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) (obviously)
  - [Android-Apt](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt)
  - [Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo)
  - [Spoon](https://github.com/square/spoon)
  - [Fabric](https://fabric.io/)
  - [ErrorProne](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-errorprone-plugin)

Like I said above, I think it might have something to do with what's happening under the hood. It's likely that something is adding the `java.util.Objects` (which isn't available on API 16). Anybody have information that may be of use to me? How would I go about circumventing this without upping my minSdkVersion?

Comment: Retrolambda should instrument your application classes only. Did you check/grep the target directory classes for `java.util.Objects`?